# Python overload single argument

Tags: python, overloading, python-typing

Let's assume I have a function with many arguments, e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd

def f(df: pd.DataFrame, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int, inplace: bool = True) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

The function will modify the dataframe if `inplace=True` and return a modified copy if `inplace=False`.

I know I can do

```py
@overload
def f(df: pd.DataFrame, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int, inplace: Literal[True] = True) -> None:
    ...

@overload
def f(df: pd.DataFrame, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int, inplace: Literal[False] = True) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ...
```

to inform the typing system about this fact.

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without repeating the entire function definition, which seems cumbersome if there are many arguments. I'm looking for something like

```py
@overload
def f(..., inplace: Literal[True]) -> None:
    ...

@overload
def f(..., inplace: Literal[False]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ...
```

**EDIT:** Several persons have made the point that the API design itself may be flawed. While this may be true, in this particular case I am retrospectively adding type hints to an existing library and changing the interface is not an option.

Comment: `inplace=False` just copies the DF in the first line of the function. The rest of it works in-place on `df` which is/copied the dataframe that was passed.

Comment: @roganjosh How do you know that and why is it relevant for the question?

Comment: It's not what the code does currently  @mkrieger1 - that's the sensible solution. Design the function to work in-place and if you don't want that, immediately copy the df you pass to the function. No need for duplication of function definitions

Comment: `if not inplace: df = df.copy()` . Job done

Comment: That's not the question here. The question is how to write the type annotations more concisely.

Comment: @mkrieger1 is it? If you get to the point that you duplicate entire function definitions with `@overload` to satisfy mypy then something has gone very wrong

Comment: That's surely the point that retro-fitted type defs are now just dictating code flow in a way that is so easily avoidable

Comment: Overloading, like the ability to define custom metaclasses, is probably used far more often than it *should* be simply because it's *available*.

Comment: Why not always return the dataframe, regardless of `inplace` or not?  Seems like it could be useful if you need `inplace` for performance reasons (or whatever) but you also want to chain one or more subsequent operations after `f`.

Comment: @roganjosh I would strongly suggest you go back and read the question more carfully. Your comments clearly show that you didn't actually understand what is being asked. With 'definitions' They clearly just mean having to duplicate the header, not the function body.

Comment: @MegaIng I strongly suggest that you read back through the question for the context. If you want polymorphism to either return a copy or not (and that basis alone) to do exactly the same thing, then the interface needs rethinking.

Comment: There's a number of people injecting their own interpretations into this question but, what I'm seeing is a Java-type interface planted into Python where there only condition is whether something happens inplace or not, and that doesn't take two function definitions in python. There's an answer that satisfies the type checking for combining the two.

Comment: With your last edit the answer is no. There is no way to do this without explicitly writing out the entire call signature for each overload. Aside from rolling your own plugin for the type checker of your choice.

Comment: Are you writing the annotations inline or using `.pyi`s? Not a workaround, but if you are using `.pyi`s, you can cut a substantial amount of work by programmatically generating the `@typing.overload`s using the `ast` module.

Answer (score 3):

One function with a boolean flag to alter its behavior like this is an anti-pattern. There should be two functions: one that modifies in-place and returns `None`, the other that returns a modified copy. (Cf. `list.sort` and `sorted`.)

That doesn't mean you need to duplicate behavior; it just means one of the functions will be a thin wrapper around the other.

```
import pandas as pd


def inplace_f(df: pd.DataFrame, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int) -> None:
    ...


def f(df: pd.DataFrame, a: int, b: int, c: int, d:int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    copy = df.copy()
    inplace_f(copy)
    return copy
```

Now, you just use the former Boolean argument to decide which function to use. That is, for example,

```
f(df, ..., inplace)
```

becomes

```
(inplace_f if inplace else f)(df, ...)
```

If your objection is that this is more complicated than the "simple" call, then you are ignoring the fact that the "simple" call isn't that simple, because it clearly doesn't make sense to call `f` with `inplace=False` if you aren't doing anything with the return value. Context already means you have some notion of what the value of `inplace` is, so it's not going to be any harder to pick the right function than it will be to supply a Boolean argument to the same function.

Comment: "One function with a boolean flag to alter its behavior like this is an anti-pattern." throws the entire `pandas` library under the bus? I'm not saying it's a gold standard, but it's a pervasive pattern

Comment: And also a lot of `numpy` which often has parameters that completely change the return values. I just guess the answer is that one has to actually duplicate the function heads, which is kind of annoying.

Comment: Though I haven't used Pandas extensively, I think "throws the entire `pandas` library under the bus" is an exaggeration. One questionable API design does not invalidate an entire library.

Comment: @chepner almost all basic transforms you can think of have `inplace=bool`.

Comment: The problem with a hard-coded argument is that it's no clearer than a proper function name would be. If I just write `f(..., True)`, I have to remember what `True` actually means in this context. This is mitigated somewhat by using a keyword argument like `f(..., inplace=True)`, but at that point, I now have two fixed strings, `f` and `inplace=True`, where I could just have *one*: `inplace_f(...)`. (1/2)

Comment: Using `overload` here just adds a lot of syntactic noise in trying to assign different static type information to two different things. (2/2)

Comment: @roganjosh I am with chepner on this and would turn the argument around: Just because a popular library like pandas extensively uses this anti-pattern does not make it good. Pandas is a type safety nightmare and while this pattern is not the main cause, it certainly does not help. And two things _can_ be true at the same time. It is confusing to me how often specific criticism is extrapolated to "throwing something under the bus".